# Google Spreadsheet text cell formatting question

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create some sort of automated formatting for certain columns (except headers of course.) to take a string of numbers (and previous formatting; which should be stripped.) and format it as

> 1234 - 5678 - 9012

for example. Now sure I do that manually now, but once other people start using the spreadsheet it's going to look ugly unless they make a small effort to keep the format.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give more details here? What different types of input are you expecting? Will the numbers always be formatted `xxxx - xxxx - xxxx`? If you could give an example of what a user enters, that would help.

Comment: @OnenOnlyWalter They may be entering the number as 123456789012, 1234-5678-9012, 1234 5679 9012, etc... Basically I want to alter it to the correct format. (spacing.)

Comment: Did the script work?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Haven't tried it yet, but I did save a copy of that example spreadsheet you made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created this little script to format the input:

```
function SCHANGE(array) {
  if(typeof(array) == 'number') {
    var number = array.toString();
  } else {
    var number = array.replace(/\D/g,'');
  }

  if(number.length != 12) {
    return "<> 12"
  } else {
    var first = number.substring(0,4);
    var mid = number.substring(4,8);
    var last = number.substring(8,12);
    var formText = first + " - " + mid + " - " + last;
  }
  return formText;
}
```

The script validates the input and converts it, checks whether 12 digits are given and returns the outcome. I've prepared an example file for you to play around with: **[formatted text](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdDNTR0pfUUtvZWxrcGRGTmJscDhnN1E&usp=sharing)**.

Comment: Thanks for this, will see if I can implement it into my spreadsheet.

Comment: In your spreadsheet, goto tools/script editor. Then paste the complete code. Save and you're on the go!